# Having trouble in getting meta_value from wp_postmeta

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I have written a plugin in wordpress to action when a post gets posted 
i am using **add_action('save_post','user_sf_project')** action for doing so.I am able to get data from **wp_post** table but not from **wp_postmeta** table. It is showing empty for it.
Need help for fetching values of **wp_postmeta**

Here is my code.

```
add_action('save_post','user_sf_project');
function user_sf_project($post_id){

$SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/soapclient/';
require_once ($SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once ($SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceHeaderOptions.php');
require_once ('Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/Samples/userAuth.php');

try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
  $mySoapClient =  $mySforceConnection->createConnection($SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login("username", "password");

  $postdata = get_post($post_id);
  $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'salary', true );
  $fields = array (
    'Name' => $post_id,
    'First_Name__c' => $postdata->post_title,
    'Salary__c' => $meta_values,
  );

  $sObject = new SObject();
  $sObject->fields = $fields;
  $sObject->type = 'NewObject__c';

  $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));

  print_r($createResponse);

  $ids = array();
  foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
    print_r($createResult);
    array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
  }

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
echo $e->faultstring;
}
```

I am unable to get meta_value from wp_postmeta using meta_key.
Please tell me what mistake i am making in my code.

Comment: Is your post_id correct? Else try using global $post; $post_id = $post->ID;

Comment: Yes $post_id is correct. it showing correct value.

Comment: $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'salary', true ); Is this one which is not working?

Comment: yes i am doing this only, but it is not working

Comment: Have you declared $post as global variable? global $post

Comment: yes, tried it also not working. It also showing wrong value of $post->ID

Comment: Try using $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID; Check if this gives correct post id.

Comment: I tried this also but still not working and this it do not show any id. I was getting right id from $post_id in my posted code and also right value for  $postdata->post_title but not showing value of $meta_values

Comment: Ok.. We'll write a custom query to get metadata.                 global $wpdb; $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts as p, wp_postmeta as m WHERE p.ID = m.post_id AND p.ID = $post_id AND m.meta_key = 'salary'"; $results = $wpdb->get_row($query); $post_meta = $results->meta_value;

Comment: i tried it and its also not working 'Salary__c' => $post_meta